# Android. How to use symbol code in TextView?

Tags: android, css, typeface, android-typeface

I am using custom font to show weather conditions (sunny, rain, snow ...). I am referencing typeface from assets/fonts folder.

```
Typeface myTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/Climacons.ttf");
TextView tvTest = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTest);
tvTest.setTypeface(myTypeface);
tvTest.setText(getString(R.string.clear_day));
```

clear_day string contains code for 'sun' symbol.

```
<string name="clear_day">\e028</string>
```

I have taken this code from its CSS:

```
Pseudo ::before element
.climacon.sun:before {
  content: "\e028";
}
```

But TextView is showing other symbols

[image]

So my question is how to show symbol in TextView using its code?

Comment: in `\e028` maybe `\ ` makes error

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
 //function
 private static final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();
 public static Typeface getFace(Context c, String assetPath) {
    synchronized (cache) {
        if (!cache.containsKey(assetPath)) {
            try {
                Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(),
                        assetPath);
                cache.put(assetPath, t);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface '" + assetPath
                        + "' because " + e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }
        return cache.get(assetPath);
    }
}

//where you use
yourView.setTypeface(getFace(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),"counterfont.ttf"));
```

Put *.ttf inside `assets` folder(`assets` is not in `res` folder!)

Then put your icon string inside `yourView` `xml`, in my case "i" is mail icon:

```
<TextView
          ...
          android:text="i"
          ...
           />
```

Comment: I know how to show symbol using character 'a', 'b', 'c'... Yes this is easy way. How I am going to know which character which symbol? In that case I should check all characters to find my symbol?

Comment: @JoeRichard noo, you should know from where you get it. I created .ttf myself , and it says which character is which symbol. Try: http://fontello.com/ , 3rd tab says which symbol  is which character, yu can edit character too